# ¿Cómo agregar un costo de envío en wordpress woocommerce tan pronto el usuario selecciona una ubicación?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, api, woocommerce

La ubicación está en un mapa de Google Map, el cual está conectado con un API que retorna el valor indicado para el costo de envío después de hacer click.

He leído sobre esto:

```
WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'delivery cost') , $value);
```

Pero parece que no está actualizando correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

ya pude encontrar la solución. Woocommerce ejecuta la función  woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees. Para agregar el costo de envío hay que hacer el llamado a una función adicional con un add_action. Además, es necesario usar la variable de sessión para guardar el valor agregado y recurrir al mismo en ejecuciones posteriores al actualizar el carrito de compras. Aquí les dejo un Snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'adicionar_costo_de_envio',10,1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_adicionar_costo_delivery', 'adicionar_costo_de_envio',10,1);
add_action('wp_ajax_adicionar_costo_delivery', 'adicionar_costo_de_envio',10,1);
function adicionar_costo_de_envio(){
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['the_fee'])) {
    $A = $_POST['the_fee'];
    $A = number_format($A,3);
    $_SESSION['costo_de_envio_en_sesion'] = $A;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['costo_de_envio_en_sesion'])) {
    $fee = $_SESSION['costo_de_envio_en_sesion'];
    WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'El costo de su envío será: ') , $fee , true, 'otro 
mensaje');  
}
}
```

Es importante recalcar que este código también es llamado dentro de un ajax el el formulario pre-checkout.